# Неправильный вывод Java множества

Tags: java, множества

У меня есть программа для операций с множествами в битовом виде. Есть 3 класса: Set, Operations, Main.

Set:

```
public class Set<T> {

    private T[] set;

    public void setSet(T[] set) {
        this.set = (T[]) Arrays.stream(set).distinct().toArray();
    }

    public T[] getSet() {
        return set;
    }

    public Set(T[] array) {
        setSet(array);
    }

}
```

Operations:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Operations<T> {

     // Перевод в битовую строку
     public String toBitString(Set set) {
         Object[] elements = set.getSet();
         int maxElement = Arrays.stream(elements).mapToInt(e -> (int) e).max().orElse(-1);
         int bitStringLength = maxElement + 1;
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < bitStringLength; i++) {
             if (Arrays.asList(elements).contains(i)) {
                 sb.append("1");
             } else {
                 sb.append("0");
             }
         }
         return sb.toString();
     }

     // Объединение множеств
     public T[] unionSets(Set s1, Set s2) {
         String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
         String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
         int maxLength = Math.max(bitString1.length(), bitString2.length());
         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
         StringBuilder sb2 = новый StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             if (i < bitString1.length()) {
                 sb1.append(bitString1.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb1.append("0");
             }
             if (i < bitString2.length()) {
                 sb2.append(bitString2.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb2.append("0");
             }
         }
         String unionBitString = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             int bit1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb1.charAt(i)));
             int bit2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb2.charAt(i)));
             unionBitString+=(bit1|bit2);
         }
         Object[] elements = new Object[unionBitString.length() - unionBitString.replace("1", "").length()];
         int index=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < unionBitString.length(); i++) {
             if (unionBitString.charAt(i) == '1') {
                 elements[index++] = i;
             }
         }
         return(T[]) new Set(elements).getSet();
     }

     // Проверка есть ли элемент в массиве
     public boolean contains(T elem, Object[] array) {
         for (T element : (T[]) array) {
             if (elem.equals(element)) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     }

     // Сечение множеств
     public T[] intersectionSets(Set s1, Set s2) {
         String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
         String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
         int maxLength = Math.max(bitString1.length(), bitString2.length());
         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
         StringBuilder sb2 = новый StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             if (i < bitString1.length()) {
                 sb1.append(bitString1.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb1.append("0");
             }
             if (i < bitString2.length()) {
                 sb2.append(bitString2.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb2.append("0");
             }
         }
         String intersectionBitString = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             int bit1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb1.charAt(i)));
             int bit2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb2.charAt(i)));
             intersectionBitString += (bit1 & bit2);
         }
         Object[] elements = new Object[intersectionBitString.length() - intersectionBitString.replace("1", "").length()];
         int index=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < intersectionBitString.length(); i++) {
             if (intersectionBitString.charAt(i) == '1') {
                 elements[index++] = i;
             }
         }
         return(T[]) new Set(elements).getSet();
     }

     // Разница множеств
     public T[] differenceSets(Set s1, Set s2) {
         String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
         String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
         int maxLength = Math.max(bitString1.length(), bitString2.length());
         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
         StringBuilder sb2 = новый StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             if (i < bitString1.length()) {
                 sb1.append(bitString1.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb1.append("0");
             }
             if (i < bitString2.length()) {
                 sb2.append(bitString2.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb2.append("0");
             }
         }
         String differenceBitString = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             int bit1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb1.charAt(i)));
             int bit2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb2.charAt(i)));
             differenceBitString += (bit1 & ~bit2);
         }
         Object[] elements = new Object[differenceBitString.length() - differenceBitString.replace("1", "").length()];
         int index=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < differenceBitString.length(); i++) {
             if (differenceBitString.charAt(i) == '1') {
                 elements[index++] = i;
             }
         }
return(T[]) new Set(elements).getSet();
 }

 // Симметричная разница множеств
 public T[] symmetricDiffSets(Set s1, Set s2) {
     String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
     String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
     int maxLength = Math.max(bitString1.length(), bitString2.length());
     StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
     StringBuilder sb2 = новый StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
         if (i < bitString1.length()) {
             sb1.append(bitString1.charAt(i));
         } else {
             sb1.append("0");
         }
         if (i < bitString2.length()) {
             sb2.append(bitString2.charAt(i));
         } else {
             sb2.append("0");
         }
     }
     String symmetricDiffBitString = "";
     for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
         int bit1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb1.charAt(i)));
         int bit2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb2.charAt(i)));
         symmetricDiffBitString += (bit1^bit2);
     }
     Object[] elements = new Object[symmetricDiffBitString.length() - symmetricDiffBitString.replace("1", "").length()];
     int index=0;
     for (int i = 0; i < symmetricDiffBitString.length(); i++) {
         if (symmetricDiffBitString.charAt(i) == '1') {
             elements[index++] = i;
         }
     }
     return(T[]) new Set(elements).getSet();
 }

 public T[] cartesianProduct(Set s1, Set s2) {
     String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
     String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
     int maxLength = Math.max(bitString1.length(), bitString2.length());
     StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
     StringBuilder sb2 = новый StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
         if (i < bitString1.length()) {
             sb1.append(bitString1.charAt(i));
         } else {
             sb1.append("0");
         }
         if (i < bitString2.length()) {
             sb2.append(bitString2.charAt(i));
         } else {
             sb2.append("0");
         }
     }
     List<Object[]> elementsList = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
         int bit1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb1.charAt(i)));
         int bit2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb2.charAt(i)));
         if (bit1 == 1 && bit2 == 1) {
             Object[] elements = new Object[2];
             elements[0] = i - bitString2.length() + 1;
             elements[1] = i - bitString1.length() + 1;
             elementsList.add(elements);
         }
     }
     Object[] cartesianArray = new Object[elementsList.size()];
     int index=0;
     for (Object[] elements : elementsList) {
         cartesianArray[index++] = elements;
     }
     return (T[]) cartesianArray;
 }

}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Set set1 = new Set(new Object[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
         Set set2 = new Set(new Object[]{3, 4, 8, 7, 5, 2});
         Set set3 = new Set(new Object[]{3, 6, 7, 1, 9, 2});

         Operations op = new Operations();

         Object[] toBitstring1 = new String[]{op.toBitString(set2)};
         Object[] toBitstring2 = new String[]{op.toBitString(set3)};

         Object[] union = op.unionSets(set2, set3);
         Object[] intersection = op.intersectionSets(set2, set3);
         Object[] difference = op.differenceSets(set2, set3);
         Object[] symmetricDiff = op.symmetricDiffSets(set2, set3);

         Object[] cartesianProduct = op.cartesianProduct(set2, set3);
         System.out.println("Универсальное множество: " + Arrays.toString(set1.getSet()));

         System.out.println("Множество 1: " + Arrays.toString(set2.getSet()));

         System.out.println("Множество 2: " + Arrays.toString(set3.getSet()));

         System.out.println("Множество 1 в битах: " + Arrays.toString(toBitstring1));
         System.out.println("Множество 2 в битах: " + Arrays.toString(toBitstring2));

         System.out.println("Объединение множеств:" + Arrays.toString(union));

         System.out.println("Сечение множеств: " + Arrays.toString(intersection));

         System.out.println("Различие множеств(set2 - set3): " + Arrays.toString(difference));

         System.out.println("Симметричная разница множеств:" + Arrays.toString(symmetricDiff));

         System.out.println("Декартовое произведение:" + Arrays.toString(cartesianProduct));

     }
}
```

Вывод

```
Универсальное множество: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Множество 1: [3, 4, 8, 7, 5, 2]
Множество 2: [3, 6, 7, 1, 9, 2]
Множество 1 в битах: [001111011]
Множество 2 в битах: [0111001101]
Объединение множеств: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Сечение множеств: [2, 3, 7]
Разница множеств (set2 – set3): [4, 5, 8]
Симметричная разница множеств: [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
Декартовое произведение: [[Ljava.lang.Object;@36f6e879, [Ljava.lang.Object;@5a61f5df, [Ljava.lang.Object;@3551a94]
```

Проблема в последнем методе, помогите исправить.

Все методы должны выполняться над полученными на предыдущем шаге битовыми строками. Если можете переписать ласт метод, буду очень признателен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После всех проделываемых в методе `cartesianProduct()` действий вы в итоге возвращаете, по сути, массив массивов типа `Object`.
Поэтому результат отработки метода `Arrays::toString` в `Main` вполне ожидаем: он проходится по массиву массивов и возвращает хэш-код каждого внутреннего массива.

Для того, чтобы возвращать то, что вы хотите, а именно числа, можно воспользоваться методом `Arrays::deepToString`. Он будет возвращать "правильное" строковое представление в том числе и для всех внутренних массивов:

```
System.out.println("Декартовое произведение:" + Arrays.deepToString(cartesianProduct));
```

Результат:

```
Декартовое произведение:[[-7, -6], [-6, -5], [-2, -1]]
```

---

Касательно остального кода, в нём сложно разобраться, но что я заметил, так это использование "сырой" формы созданного вами обобщённого класса `Set`, например, при передаче в методы.

Это приводит к тому, что даже когда вы при возврате из метода кастуете какой-то массив к `T[]`, то фактически он остаётся массивом типа `Object`. Например, так происходит в том же методе `cartesianProduct()`. Хотя это уже отдельная тема.

Comment: блин, так метод же совсем не так работает как должен был(((, нужно заново писать

Comment: возможно знаете как его правильно переписать?

Comment: он должен был вывести 36 пар, а вывел только 3

Comment: @HEISENBERG, заголовок у вашего вопроса "Неправильный вывод Java множества", и в самом вопросе вы написали "Проблема в последнем методе". На мой взгляд, текущий ответ от Byb достаточно точно отвечает на ваш вопрос и решает проблему "неправильного вывода". Если у вас есть другой конкретный вопрос, то [задайте его отдельно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), указав в нем все необходимые детали. Если вам помог текущий ответ, то засчитайте его, нажав на галочку слева от ответа.